# Formulário em HTML+PHP+Jquery para editar senha aparece janela padrão do Chrome

Tags: formulário, google-chrome

Fiz um formulário para edição de senha e a ação esperada é um submit no onclick, mas pelo contrário é exibida uma tela para gerenciamento do Chrome, eu não habilitei esta opção e ela persiste em todos os sites que me permitem alterar minha senha pessoal.

O código é simples:

```
<form role="form" id="formEditPassword" class="formEditPassword" onSubmit="return false;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="novopass" class="novopass form-control" name="novopass" required placeholder="Nova senha (mínimo 5 digitos)">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="cfrmpass" class="cfrmpass form-control" name="cfrmpass" required placeholder="Confirme a senha (mínimo 5 digitos)">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="atualpass" class="atualpass form-control" name="atualpass" required placeholder="Sua senha atual">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <a class="form-link" href="form-reset">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="returnData"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSendForm" class="btn btn-default vcenter">Salvar alterações</button>
</form>
<script>
$("#btnSendForm").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "form-password",
        data: $("#formEditPassword").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('.returnData').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Mas ao clicar em enviar, como acontecia em outros casos com a mesma fonte, agora aparece a janela abaixo, o campo valida mas aparece a janela obstruindo a experiência do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia fornecer detalhes suficientes, tais como código e como você esperaria de sua aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia.

Me parece normal. Veja, se há diversos usuários do mesmo site com seus logins salvos, ele abrirá essa janela, perguntando a que usuário a senha se refere.

O que tu podes fazer é dar um Esc (geralmente cancela/fecha janela), ou pode ir nas configurações do navegador e apagar todas as contas relacionadas a este site. Quando o navegador perguntar novamente, escolha uma opção similar a "Nunca perguntar novamente", ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Santa ignorância a minha, faz sentido, mas penso em usuários da interface que não sabem também, confuso, vou limpar os dados armazenados de senhas para continuar os testes, obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia, Eliseu. O teu "Santa ignorância" me lembrou o Robin do Batman anos 50, ou o Donatelo das Tartarugas Ninja (risos), mas não precisa exagerar. Bom trabalho e um ótimo dia.